# Java create a Process with String as stdin

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I'm trying to launch a process, created with `ProcessBuilder` which is expecting piped input. What I mean is, when run from the terminal the command will look like `escaped_text | process --opt1`. Please note, the process does not wait for user input and behaves quite differently when its `stdin` is empty. So, writing to a processes `stdin` will not work.

The docs for `ProcessBuilder` suggest the method [redirectInput](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectInput(java.io.File)) will create a Process with its `stdin` set to a `File`. The problem is, I have the modified file contents already loaded into a `String`. I don't see the point of having to write the content to a temp file only for the process to open and read that file.

Is there a way to manually create the `Process` with a `StreamReader` or similar configured as its `stdin`?